# Tmux failed to connect to server error on `tmux ls` when there are no running sessions

Tags: bash, tmux

Just writing a quick loop to list out existing tmux sessions when I log into a server, depending on whether tmux is installed (via .bashrc on CentOS).

```
if rpm -q tmux; then
    echo -e "TMUX sessions running:\n"
    echo `tmux ls`
fi
```

This works great when tmux has a session or two, but if there are no running tmux sessions, I'm getting `failed to connect to server: No such file or directory`.

Is there a way to suppress this?

Thanks!

Comment: Redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`

Comment: There is no reason for the echo on that `tmux ls` line. It is entirely pointless (and actively harmful of the `ls` output's spacing).

Comment: Both of your comments were helpful, and I have the output I wanted. Still unclear why tmux would output an error in the presence of no sessions, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a combination of @Barmar and @Etan Reisner 's advice:

```
tmux ls 2> /dev/null
```

Nothing is echoed in when there are no sessions, otherwise the list is reported.

Answer (score 29):

Note that you may have a tmux server running, but you cannot connect to it because someone cleaned out the `/tmp` directory and took the server's socket with it.

In that case, you can tell the server to recreate the socket by sending it a SIGUSR1 signal.

```
% ps aux | grep -w [t]mux
root     14799  0.2  0.0  36020   488 ?        Ss   May08  51:30 tmux
% kill -USR1 14799
% tmux ls
<list of tmux sessions>
```